# Program does not display all records, only the last record entered

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, list, iterator

I am currently working on this Java web app with Hibernate framework wherein it will display all records from the database. However, the program only lists the last record entered in all rows. (Meaning, if I have 5 different existing data, the program displays 5 rows with data of the last record entered. So it is just repeating what the values of the last row are.)

I couldn't figure out what is wrong with the code:

```
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.configure();

    SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();

    Session session = factory.openSession();

    Query query = session.createQuery("from mytable");

    for (Iterator iterator = query.iterate(); iterator.hasNext();)
    {
        MyTable record = (MyTable) iterator.next();

        System.out.println("id: " + record.getId());
        System.out.println("firstName: " + record.getFirstName());
        System.out.println("lastName: " + record.getLastName());
        System.out.println("due: " + record.getDue());
        System.out.println("email: " + record.getEmail());
        System.out.println("website: " + record.getWebsite());
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no error in inserting the data and not with displaying them?

Comment: I don't have the data insertion yet. For the meantime, I am inserting sample data directly to the database.

Comment: Ok have you checked that you don't accidentally insert the same data?

Comment: yes, they all actually differ from each other.

Comment: Code looks good might be issue when displaying data

Comment: @AbdullahShaikh, this is the actual code for displaying the data, so your statement is a bit contradictional.

Comment: @theGreatDane, I insist, can you provide the code you use to insert the data?

Comment: As I previously mentioned, I do not have the code yet for inserting  the data. Anyway, do the hibernate config and mapping matter to the result of iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Try using list instead:

```
List entities = session.createQuery("from mytable").list();
for (Object o : entities) {
    MyTable record = (MyTable) o;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Then you don't have any data to load. Are you connecting to the same DB? Log SQL queries and run them against DB.

Comment: There are data being displayed. The problem is it only display the last record entered in all rows.

Comment: Paste the executed SQL and run it in a console to get the actual selected records. Then paste the SQL result too.